# why does the graphics on java output nothing?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe

Below is code I received directly from my teacher but it outputs nothing! all I see is a blank window open and nothing is displayed in it. I can not understand why please help!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class IntroToGraphics extends JFrame
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    public IntroToGraphics() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super("howdy");
        setSize(1500,850);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public void Paint(Graphics g) {
            g.drawString("Hello World",1000,450);
            g.fillRect(200,200,50,50);
    }
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        new IntroToGraphics();
    }
}
```

If anything isn't clear please let me know and I will fix it promptly.

Comment: `Paint` is not `paint`. Method names (except for constructor) by convention are snakeCase (starting with lowercase), and `java.awt.Window` defines `paint` as the method to be overridden; you end up defining a new method instead of overriding one, which never gets called.

Comment: You seriously need to have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to get a better idea of how painting works and how you should work with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `Paint` name should be `paint`. In addition, it is better to use `@Override` annotation since you have overridden the paint method.[image]

The Output will be

[image]

Comment: Thank you! that has been giving me pain for 8 hours!